# How to reinstate files from an rdfind (removes duplicates) summary text file

Tags: files, copy, text

I have used rdfind to remove duplicate files. It produces a `results.txt` file. This shows the first of the duplicate files which it did not remove and then the list of all the duplicates that  were removed. Here is a sample from that text file.

```
DUPTYPE_FIRST_OCCURRENCE 8644 2 27882216 2065 49681972 3 
         /media/r/WDE4/BU/Downloads/03.mp4

DUPTYPE_WITHIN_SAME_TREE -8644 2 27882216 2065 38020226 3                   
         /media/r/WDE4/g5/Downloads/03.mp4

DUPTYPE_WITHIN_SAME_TREE -8644 2 27882216 2065 55051289 3 
        /media/r/WDE4/BUg6/WhatsApp/WA.mp4

DUPTYPE_WITHIN_SAME_TREE -8644 1 27882216 2065 18613496 3 
        /media/r/WDE4/hl/CCWA0002.mp4

DUPTYPE_WITHIN_SAME_TREE -8644 2 27882216 2065 38021426 3 
        /media/r/WDE4/g5/Downloads/ZZ2.mp4

DUPTYPE_WITHIN_SAME_TREE -8644 2 27882216 2065 48497985 3          
        /media/r/WDE4/BUg60/WhatsApp/2.mp4


DUPTYPE_FIRST_OCCURRENCE 8424 2 30668643 2065 49682079 3 
        /media/r/WDE4/BU/Downloads/zzz.zip

DUPTYPE_WITHIN_SAME_TREE -8424 0 30668643 2065 18612483 3 
        /media/r/WDE4/zzz.zip

DUPTYPE_WITHIN_SAME_TREE -8424 2 30668643 2065 38020027 3 
        /media/r/WDE4/g5/Downloads/zz22.zip

DUPTYPE_FIRST_OCCURRENCE 8491 2 30672140 2065 49682078 3 
        /media/r/WDE4/BU/Downloads/z3.zip

DUPTYPE_WITHIN_SAME_TREE -8491 2 30672140 2065 38020084 3 
        /media/r/WDE4/g5/Downloads/One.zip

DUPTYPE_WITHIN_SAME_TREE -8491 1 30672140 2065 18612482 3 
        /media/r/WDE4/C/One2.zip

DUPTYPE_FIRST_OCCURRENCE 70405 3 30695973 2065 26739252 3 
        /media/r/WDE4/WDE/LGFULL12/D/C.mp4

DUPTYPE_WITHIN_SAME_TREE -70405 2 30695973 2065 29886532 3 
        /media/r/WDE4/WDE/LGR40/C.mp4

DUPTYPE_FIRST_OCCURRENCE 195982 2 30953302 2065 49172850 3 
        /media/r/WDE4/WDEX/P/d/MVI_1762.AVI

DUPTYPE_WITHIN_SAME_TREE -195982 2 30953302 2065 49172073 3 
        /media/r/WDE4/WDEX/P/zMVI_1762.AVI

DUPTYPE_WITHIN_SAME_TREE -195982 2 30953302 2065 49173627 3 
        /media/r/WDE4/WDEX/P/MVI_1762.AVI

DUPTYPE_WITHIN_SAME_TREE -195982 2 30953302 2065 49176978 3 
        /media/r/WDE4/WDEX/G/MVI_1762.AVI
```

Every line starts with `DUPTYPE_FIRST_OCCURRENCE` for the file which still exists or `DUPTYPE_WITHIN_SAME_TREE` for a file which has been deleted.

I would like to supply a folder name and have all of the folder reinstated with its original files. For example,  given `/media/r/WDE4/WDEX/P` all of the P folder would be reinstated with its original files - in this case `MVI_1762.AVI` and `zMVI_1762.AVI`. If I would have asked for `/media/r/WDE4` then everything would be reinstated.

Please note that the list is in size order so there could be many files belonging to `P` throughout the `results.txt` file. Also `rdfind` does not use the actual file names for finding duplicates.

Some Pseudocode:

```
loop  
   Look for a FIRST line  
   Save that lines file's details as X  
   Look at every TREE line  
     If it contains the supplied path  
        copy the file X to the supplied path  
        rename the file to the name in this TREE line  
endloop
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to *undo* an `rdfind` operation, yes?

Comment: Yes undo an rdfind operation - but only for particular folders and not the whole rdfind operation. Thanks for the correct formatting.

Answer (score 0):

just plain bash is enough for this:

```
src=""
cat results.txt | while { read op o1 o2 o3 o4 o5 o6 file ; } do
    if [ "$op" == "DUPTYPE_FIRST_OCCURRENCE" ] ; then 
        src="$file"
    elif [ "$op" == "DUPTYPE_WITHIN_SAME_TREE" ] ; then 
        echo "Copying " "$src" " to " "$file"
        cp "$src" "$file" 
    else
        echo "ignoring $op"
    fi 
done
```